# Archiving MongoDB data to S3, with retryable steps

Tags: python, error-handling, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have a python script to archive some data (export from mongo to a local json file and then upload it to s3)

Is there a better way to implement/improve the current flow? Each step should be be retried in case of failure and if the step is still failing after the set no of retries it shouldn't run the other steps but continue with the archiving for the other records.

```
    archived = 0
    flow_status = False
    for metadata_id in metadata_ids:
        logging.info("Archiving snapshot with metadata_id %s", metadata_id)

        # Export snapshot to a temp JSON file
        for retry in range(0, 3):
            flow_status = dump_snapshot(mongo, database, collection, str(metadata_id), folder_path, dry_run)
            if not flow_status:
                logging.info("Failed to export snapshot %s to json file. Retry no %s", str(metadata_id), retry)
            else:
                logging.info("Successfully exported snapshot %s to json file.", str(metadata_id))
                break

        if not flow_status:
            logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to export to json file. ", str(metadata_id))
            continue

        # Save the temp file to S3
        file_path = folder_path + '/' + database + '/' + collection + '/' + str(metadata_id) + '.json'
        aws_path = "archived_snapshots/" + database + '/' + collection + '/' + str(metadata_id) + '.json'
        for retry in range(0, 3):
            flow_status = aws.upload_file(file_path, aws_path, dry_run)
            if not flow_status:
                logging.info("Failed to save snapshot file %s to s3. Retry no %s", str(metadata_id), retry)
            else:
                logging.info("Successfully saved snapshot %s to s3.", str(metadata_id))
                break

        if not flow_status:
            logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to saved file to s3. ", str(metadata_id))
            continue

        # Validate the file exists on S3 and has the correct checksum
        if not aws.check_file_exists(aws_path) or not aws.validate_s3_obj(file_path, aws_path):
           logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to validate file. ", str(metadata_id))
           continue

        # Delete temp file
        if not dry_run:
            delete_file(file_path)

        # Set the archive_status to "ArchivedToPurge" in the MongoDB metadata collection
        metadata_collection = collection + "_metadata"
        for retry in range(0, 3):
            flow_status = update_archive_status(mongo.client[database][metadata_collection], metadata_collection,
                                                metadata_id, archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name, dry_run)
            if not flow_status:
                logging.info("Failed to update snapshot metadata for %s to %s. Retry no %s", metadata_collection +
                             "/" + str(metadata_id), archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name, retry)
            else:
                logging.info("Updated snapshot metadata for %s to %s", metadata_collection + "/" + str(metadata_id),
                             archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name)
                break

        if not flow_status:
            logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to update metadata to %s", str(metadata_id),
                          archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name)
            continue

        # Delete the documents in MongoDB
        logging.info("Deleting snapshots with metadata_id %s from collection %s", str(metadata_id), collection)
        for retry in range(0, 3):
            if dry_run:
                break
            records_count = mongo_count(mongo.client[database][collection], match={"metadata_id": metadata_id})
            deleted_count = mongo_delete(mongo.client[database][collection], {"metadata_id": metadata_id})
            flow_status = deleted_count == records_count
            if not flow_status:
                logging.info("Failed to delete all records of snapshot with metadata_id %s. Deleted %s out of %s "
                             "records", str(metadata_id), deleted_count, records_count)
            else:
                logging.info("Deleted %s records of snapshot with metadata_id %s from collection %s",
                             deleted_count, str(metadata_id), collection)
                break

        if not flow_status:
            logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to delete all snapshot records.",
                          str(metadata_id))
            continue

        # Set the archive_status to "ArchivedAndPurged" in the MongoDB metadata collection.
        for retry in range(0, 3):
            flow_status = update_archive_status(mongo.client[database][metadata_collection], metadata_collection,
                                                metadata_id, archiving_status.ArchivedAndPurged.name, dry_run)
            if not flow_status:
                logging.info("Failed to update snapshot metadata for %s to %s. Retry no %s", metadata_collection +
                             "/" + str(metadata_id), archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name, retry)
            else:
                logging.info("Updated snapshot metadata for %s to %s", metadata_collection + "/" + str(metadata_id),
                             archiving_status.ArchivedToPurge.name)
                break

        if not flow_status:
            logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s.  Failed to update metadata to %s.", str(metadata_id),
                          archiving_status.ArchivedAndPurged.name)
            continue
```

Any tips/advice?

Comment: Without definitions for `metadata_ids`, `dump_snapshot`, etc. this is going to be difficult to meaningfully review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice code.

#### In Python, `for` has `else` clause

And I think it fits here perfectly. In

```
for retry in range(3):
    if ...:
        break
else:
    #else-part
```

the `else-part` will be executed if there was no break. So:

```
    for retry in range(0, 3):
        if dump_snapshot(mongo, database, collection, str(metadata_id), folder_path, dry_run):
            logging.info("Successfully exported snapshot %s to json file.", str(metadata_id))
        else:
            logging.info("Failed to export snapshot %s to json file. Retry no %s", str(metadata_id), retry)
            break
    else:
        logging.error("Snapshot archiving flow failed for %s. Failed to export to json file. ", str(metadata_id))
        continue
```

The code gets rid of `flow_status` and extra checks.

Other options are to make a class hierarchy for actions and use exception instead of continue (very short code in the loop and very long outside) or to make a retry function with lambda for the action and all log messages in arguments. The first is long, the second has somewhat bad readability, like:

```
retry(3,
    lambda: dump_snapshot(mongo, database, collection, str(metadata_id), folder_path, dry_run),
    "Successfully exported snapshot {} to json file.".format(str(metadata_id)),
    "Failed to export snapshot {} to json file. Retry no %d".format(str(metadata_id)),
    "Snapshot archiving flow failed for {}. Failed to export to json file. ".format(str(metadata_id)) )

def retry(count, f, success, fail_attempt, fail):
    for attempt in range(count):
        if f():
            logging.info(success)
            return
        else:
            logging.info(fail_attempt, retry)
    raise RetryFailedExeption(fail)
```

Well, it's not too bad after all. But it needs a default value for count and keywords for log messages, to make the call like this:

```
retry(lambda: dump_snapshot(mongo, database, collection, str(metadata_id), folder_path, dry_run),
    #count = 3 - skipped
    success = "Successfully exported snapshot {} to json file.".format(str(metadata_id)),
    fail    = "Failed to export snapshot {} to json file. Retry no %d".format(str(metadata_id)),
    failure = "Snapshot archiving flow failed for {}. Failed to export to json file. ".format(str(metadata_id)) )
```